# Maximum concurrent sessions by default in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot version 1.5.13. 
I can set the upper limit on concurrent sessions using the below code snippet in a configuration class -

```
http.sessionManagement().maximumSession($max_sesssions)
```

However, I want to know the default value of this limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is to allow any number of users. I navigated through the source code and found out the value is set to -1 for allowing any number of users by default.

Below is the snippet from ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy class -

```
/**
 * Sets the <tt>maxSessions</tt> property. The default value is 1. Use -1 for
 * unlimited sessions.
 *
 * @param maximumSessions the maximimum number of permitted sessions a user can have
 * open simultaneously.
 */
public void setMaximumSessions(int maximumSessions) {
    Assert.isTrue(
            maximumSessions != 0,
            "MaximumLogins must be either -1 to allow unlimited logins, or a positive integer to specify a maximum");
    this.maximumSessions = maximumSessions;
}
```

Comment: is there any `application.properties` equivalent to this.

Answer (score 1):

> According to Documentation, *the default is to allow any number of
>   users.*

```
.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(maximumSessions);
```

you can see the below details by `Ctrl` + `Click` on maximumSessions for *eclips* on *windows*.

*SessionManagementConfigurer.java*

```
/**
     * Controls the maximum number of sessions for a user. The default is to allow any
     * number of users.
     * @param maximumSessions the maximum number of sessions for a user
     * @return the {@link SessionManagementConfigurer} for further customizations
     */
    public ConcurrencyControlConfigurer maximumSessions(int maximumSessions) {
        this.maximumSessions = maximumSessions;
        return new ConcurrencyControlConfigurer();
    }
```

Comment: is there any `application.properties` equivalent to this.